# How do I make built-in bookcases for the corners of a room?

Tags: carpentry, design

I am planning some built in book shelves around a room. The issue I have is what to do at the corners of the room. That is,  how not to waste space, but to make the space useful.

The corner space could be used for storage other the books if it worked better.

Comment: Design questions are considered off-topic here, since answers will depend on personal preference. If you have a question about **implementing** a specific design, please ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 8):

You could simply make the shelves at the corner "L" shaped, like this.

[image: Corner case 1]

Another approach would be to make a corner unit, at an angle to the two wall units. Like this.

[image]

A smaller corner unit, is also an option.

[image]

Though all of these options are dependent on *your* personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is something like this:

[image]

Forgive my sloppiness in my High-Tech design software.

Comment: Your illustration is basically how all the Ikea modular systems work. Seems like a typical solution.

Comment: I was actually thinking about some kitchen cupboards I saw.  But the same idea.